# PrimeNg disabled sub MenuItem is clickable and expandable

Tags: primeng, angular16

Problem: MenuItem is disabled but still it can be expandable. How can I fix it? I have already provided "expanded: false,  disabled: true" for **New **Menu item.

Below is my code.[New menu is disabled but still I can expand it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CgZD.png)
HTML: <p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'300px'}">

this.items = [
{
label: 'File',
icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-file',
items: [
{
label: 'New',
icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus', expanded: false,  disabled: true,
items: [
{
label: 'Bookmark',
icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-bookmark',
}
],
},
{
label: 'Delete',
icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash',
},
],
},
];
}

Comment: Can you reproduce this in stalkblitz ?

Comment: primeNg Team has fixed this problem and we will get it on update in next primeNg version 16.4.2. (https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/13827)